# RecyclerView adapter is becoming null when returning to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, adapter

I have a view pager that allows me to switch between fragments.  Each fragment has an adapter, and when I switch back to the fragment, I have to call `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`, as recyclerView's adapter is becoming null, but the actual adapter variable is not. I understand it's best practice to only call setAdapter once, is there anyway to ensure that the recyclerView does not lose it's adapter until it's completely killed?

Thank you for the help ahead of time

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Please post your code to be able to understand what are you doing.